# How to Autopost Facebook status (after new layout) using Python and selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

[Facebook Image along with its xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrMJ5.png)

How to autopost my status after new Facebook layout using python and selenium... ?
Before this Update I had a perfect execution but now it says Xpath not found neither it is finding using css or tag property

Here is the code in through which I am accessing this field

```
for line in obj2:
    #timeline
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='js_9a']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").send_keys(line)  

    #post button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//[@id='js_9a']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button").click()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your post accordingly and provide what you have tried so far, including your code.

Comment: Thank you I will be editing this post with the code I have done thanks again

Comment: What's not working exactly? The inputting to the input or clicking the post button?

Comment: And can you post the element's HTML code?

Comment: Thanks so much for you time Its the time line that shows the Exception if you please see the attached Image it will become clear to you thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should workaround the task. (If I find a better way to do it I will edit the code)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time
### login details ########################
username = "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"
pwd = "xxxxxxxxx"
##########################################

### what is on my mind ###################
msg = "hey there!"
##########################################

# initializing driver and loading web
chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
# end initializing

# start login
user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="email"]""")
pwd_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pass"]""")
user_input.send_keys(username)
pwd_input.send_keys(pwd)
pwd_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# end login

# writing msg
time.sleep(3)
first_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_5qtp")
first_what_is_on_my_mind_element.click()
time.sleep(3)
second_what_is_on_my_mind_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
second_what_is_on_my_mind_element.send_keys(msg)
# end writing

# posting
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for button in buttons:
    if 'Post' in button.text:
        button.click()
# end posting
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you time but the problem remains the same (First) Its not sending the key (2nd) it raised the error unable to locate the element...... one reason (maybe) if we inspect the fields its shows the relevant tags and classes but it is not present in if we do VIEW PAGE SOURCE  
 NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft"}

Comment: I have edited it. Copy the new code and try it again.

Comment: still not working same error 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft"}

in #writing msg after second time.sleep its not sending the keys (nothing displayed on the text area facebook ) but the command execute and then when it goes to next line that is

button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft")


it throws the above mentioned Excetion

Comment: Then replace the _posting_ block code for the new block I posted.

Comment: Thanks for the Time above code still generates the exceptions but finally it is figured out how to do it. There are two things to be added 1. after #end writing  put a time.sleep(10) to write the text 2. By replacing ( if 'Post' in button.text: ) with (if button.text=='Post': ) solves the problem its because in first case it picks some POST text from page which is not a button (Although it should be) hence generating Exception
Once again thanks for your time